# Array String Method Return a multiple String Method

Tags: java, arrays, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please suggest how to return a multiple array string in an single method:

```
public ArrayList<String> scraptable() throws InterruptedException {
    pui = new Polled(driver);
    ArrayList<String> firstname = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> lastname = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> email = new ArrayList<String>();

    WebElement usertable = pui.tbl_userlist;
    List<WebElement> allRows = usertable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

    for (int row = 1; row < allRows.size(); row++) {
        String Firstname = driver.findElement(
                By.xpath("//*[@id='tbUserList']/tbody/tr[" + row
                        + "]/td[2]")).getText();
        firstname.add(Firstname);

        String Lastname = driver.findElement(
                By.xpath("//*[@id='tbUserList']/tbody/tr[" + row
                        + "]/td[3]")).getText();
        lastname.add(Lastname);

        String Email = driver.findElement(
                By.xpath("//*[@id='tbUserList']/tbody/tr[" + row
                        + "]/td[4]")).getText();
        email.add(Email);           
    }
    return null;
```

I need to return `firstname`, `lastname`, and `email` Array string, how is it possible to return multiple array string?

Answer (score 2):

You can return a list of lists. For example:

```
import java.util.Arrays; // needed to access "Arrays" class with short name

public List<ArrayList<String>> scraptable() throws InterruptedException {
    ...
    return Arrays.asList(firstname, lastname, email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature should be change and there are two ways.

With **List**

```
public List<List<String>> scraptable() throws InterruptedException {
   List<List<String>> mainlist = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
   ArrayList<String> firstname = new ArrayList<String>();
   ArrayList<String> lastname = new ArrayList<String>();
   ArrayList<String> email = new ArrayList<String>();
    ---
    ---
    --
  mainlist.add(email);
  mainlist.add(lastname);
  mainlist.add(firstname);
```

Then add them to main list and return.

Or even with **Map** ,I suggest this

```
public  Map<String, List<String>> scraptable() throws InterruptedException {

  Map<String, List<String>> mainlist = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
      ArrayList<String> firstname = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<String> lastname = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<String> email = new ArrayList<String>();

      mainlist.put("email",email);
      mainlist.put("lastname",lastname);
      mainlist.put("firstname",firstname);
```

Then some where else, getting from this map like

```
 List<String> emailsList = mainlist.get("email");
```

Answer (score 0):

Return

```
ArrayList< ArrayList < String>>
```

or create a bean containing the arrays and return it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this design

```
class SampleObject{
    String firstname;
    String lastname;
    String email;
    //getter and setter;
}

public List<ArrayList<String>> scraptable() throws InterruptedException {
    ArrayList<SampleObject> listofObjects= new ArrayList<SampleObject>();

     for (int row = 1; row < allRows.size(); row++) {
         SampleObject s= new SampleObject();

         listofObjects.add(s);
     }
    return listofObjects;
}
```

or if you stick on you code then use below one.

```
public List<ArrayList<String>> scraptable() throws InterruptedException {
    List<List<String>>  listOfList =new ArrayList<List<String>> ();

   listOfList.add(firstname); 
   listOfList.add(lastname);
   listOfList.add(email);
    return listOfList ;
}
```